# Is it possible to remap the character following CTRL+R in INSERT mode?

Tags: key-bindings

While in INSERT mode, I'd like to make `<c-r>*` behave as `<c-r>+`. Is that possible?

I tried both of the following, but no luck:

```
inoremap <c-r>* <c-r>+
onoremap * +
```

Is it possible to do it?

EDIT, Dec 11th: The solution I tried (`inoremap <c-r>* <c-r>+`) is the answer, but sometimes that doesn't always work, and I'm not entirely sure why (it might have to do with timeouts as mentioned in the comments, and sometimes the timeout behavior changes on me at some random point into my NeoVim session).

EDIT, Dec 12th: This is what I'm trying to achieve, as per a comment I wrote in my vimrc:

```
    " COPY/PASTE
        " Make "* behave the same on all OSes. In linux, "* uses the
        " SECONDARY register for pasting with a mouse middle click, but I
        " never use that. In OS X, "* uses the same register as "+, which
        " is the behavior I like.
            noremap "* "+
            inoremap <c-r>* <c-r>+
```

Comment: Operator-pending mode has nothing to do with `<C-r>`, it is for normal-mode commands like `d`. First variant does work for me, if it does not for you check `:h timeoutlen` and `:h timeout`.

Comment: It is also possible that first mapping does not work as you are in compatible mode. Specifically `&cpoptions` setting must *not* contain `<`. Fixed either by adding `set nocompatible` explicitly at the start of the vimrc (and verifying that no command adds `<` to `&cpoptions` later), or by using `inoremap <special> <C-r>* <C-r>+`. This variant is rather unlikely because Vim starts in nocompatible mode when it finds `~/.vimrc` file (except for the case when you used `-u ~/.vimrc`).

Comment: The first mapping works fine for me. Another reason why it might not work for you would be if you have set `notimeout`, or you have set `timeoutlen` or `ttimeoutlen` too low. `:verb set timeout? timeoutlen? ttimeoutlen?` to check.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Here's my timeout config: http://trusktr.io:7777/xepuhoduki.

Comment: Alright, so it seems to be working for me now. I disabled `set notimeout`, but then I re-enabled it, and now it keeps working. It's strange to me. Maybe there's a subtle bug in Neovim, as I've had the timeout behavior randomly change after a while too...

Comment: Why not `set clipboard^=unnamedplus clipboard^=unnamed`?

Comment: @romainl `set clipboard^=unnamedplus clipboard^=unnamed` doesn't do the same thing. I want to explicitly copy to, or paste from my desktop clipboard with `"*yy`, `"*dd`, `"*p`, etc. Otherwise, I don't want (neo)vim to touch the desktop clipboard on normal operations without "* (the behavior I'm talking about is the default for Vim for OS X, and I'm just trying to emulate that in Linux). Basically, these two commands seem to make it happen: `noremap "* "+` and `inoremap <c-r>* <c-r>+`.

Comment: This is not a Vim issue at all; this is obviously a system-level issue and you are taking it from the wrong angle. On linux/bsd you can use a very small program called [autocutsel](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) to synchronize the PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD "clipboards".

Comment: @romainl You may be right! But this vim solution turned out to be quick and simple in the only ever instance of this "system issue" getting in the way of my workflow, so it's a good enough solution for me. Thanks for the input. :]

Comment: @trusktr you should post an answer to your own question so this can be marked answered.